# Connecting 2 PCs using a dual port ethernet card

Tags: ethernet, crossover

I have a PC with a lot of harddisks and I would like to access to these disks from an other machine. I know alredy, that 2 ethernet cards can be connected directly, using a special crossover cable.
The only limitation is, the other machine has only some of the old PCI slots free. (The PCI-express slots are alredy in use.) My idea is to buy 2 dual port gigabit ethernet cards (like the [ZEXMTE Gigabit Ethernet PCI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076Q3C4WF))
so i could have 2Gbit/sec transfer rates, which is enough for me.
(There are alredy 10Gbit ethernet cards on the market, but they all use PCI-express and not the old PCI interface.)

Can I connect the 2 ports of the 2 cards with a crossover cable without an extra switch or router ?
Could I really reach the 2Gbit/sec (or similar) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2Gbit/sec maybe it all depends on windowing. The cable you are talking about can be made as well.  You have to switch cables 1 ==> 3, 2 ==> 6 on one side.  You will also have to statically assign the IP addresses.  Make sure each port are on the same ip schema (192.168.0.x)  and subnet (255.255.255.0) which is connected to each other.  Share the folder or use the admin share (c$) and map the drive.

Comment: Ok, thanx. To make it clear: if I have this dual port card, do I have 2 ip addresses on both machines, or does the card automatically a bonding, so only 1 ip address will show up ?

Comment: You can do either.  It will not "automatically bond" you will have to manually do it.  it is in the ethernet settings if you right click on it.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/172359/highspeed-data-sharing-between-two-computers) someone mentioned, that the transfer was slow using a crossover cable with a Gbit ethernet card. I alredy did a crossconnect between 100Mbit cards, and the speed was NOT slow. Is something special with the Gbit 
 ethernet?

Comment: @awgold90 GbE mandates auto MDI-X on all ports, which means you _shouldn't_ need a crossover cable for it at all.  Some poorly designed GbE NIC's (usually cheap knockoffs of name brands) are designed with this in mind, and don't properly handle crossover cables (because they assume everyone will just use straight through cables).